# Related Rates with Melting Snowball Homework Help

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

In my Calculus 1 class we are currently studying implicit differentiation and related rates. I have one last homework problem that I simply cannot get right. Our math homework is done on an online program which uses **jsMath v3.4e**, so I'm wondering if I had the correct answer at one point and it is not accepting my decimals to 8-10 decimal places. Either way, I have 3 tries left on this problem and I can't waste more tries.

**Here is the question:** "The sun is shining and a spherical snowball of volume 180 cubic feet is melting at a rate of 16 cubic feet per hour. As it melts, it remains spherical. At what rate is the radius changing after 2 hours?"

**My solution:**

So from the question, we are given two things:

1. $$\frac {dV}{dt} = -16 \frac{ft^3}{hr}$$
2. $$V = 180 {ft^3}$$ *the volume before it starts melting*

So what I preceded to do was find the radius of this snowball.

1. $$V = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$$
2. $$180 = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$$
3. $$ r = \sqrt[3]{\frac {15}{\pi}} $$

Then I differentiated the Volume of a Sphere equation

$$\frac {dV}{dt} = 4\pi r^2 \frac{dr}{dt} $$

I realized that after 2 hours, the $$\frac {dV}{dt} = -32\frac{ft^3}{hr} $$ 
because $$-16\frac{ft^3}{hr} * 2 hours = -32\frac{ft^3}{hr} $$

so then I plugged in everything into the differentiated formula

1. $$\frac {dV}{dt} = 4\pi r^2 \frac{dr}{dt}$$
2. $$-32 = 4\pi (\sqrt[3]{\frac {15}{\pi}})^2 $$
3. and I got $$\frac {dr}{dt} = -0.8980748271 \frac{ft}{hr}$$

I have tried looking this problem up several times and trying it different ways but with no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: The rate at which the volume is changing is constant, so $$\frac{dV}{dt} = -16~\frac{\text{ft}^2}{\text{h}}$$  What is changing is the radius and the volume of the sphere.  You need to find the radius and volume after two hours to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V(t)=180-16t=\frac{4\pi r(t)^3}{3}$

$r(t)=\left(\frac{3(180-16t)}{4\pi}\right)^\frac{1}{3}$

$\left.\frac{\operatorname{d}r(t)}{\operatorname{d}t}\right|_{t=2}=-\frac{4}{\sqrt[3]{111^2\pi}}\approx-0.11824824793$

Comment: Spot on answer.

Answer (score 0):

One mistake I noticed is that you tried to find what the radius equals at time $t=0$, but you want to know what $r$ is when $t=2$. The volume at that time is $180-2(16) = 148$. Hence $r = \sqrt[3]{3(148)/(4\pi)} = \sqrt[3]{111/\pi}$.

Comment: ... and in addition to that $dV/dt$ is still $-16$, even after two hours, it does not double as the OP said.

Comment: Agreed. (I'd upvote that comment if I had the reputation.)